# how to enable @Preview for compose multiplatform for IOS?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack, composable, compose-multiplatform

I am working on an application using compose multiplatform. I wanted to preview my ios app as well can we do that in android studio ? we can do that in android.
sharing screenshots of android [image: ANDROID SCREEN PREVIEW COMPOSABLE WRITTEN IN COMMON MAIN]

[image: HERE IS THE CODE OF ANDROID MAIN WHERE APP FUNCTION IS WRITTEN IN COMMONMAIN]